# How do you get a notification when a user with your app user updates their status

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to make a facebook app that needs to do something when a user updates their status.  How would I make facebook notify my app when a user updates their status?

I know this is possible because the twitter app updates your twitter status when update your facebook status.  I'm looking to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the status.get function (It's Beta ATM), and poll.

You could subscribe to the user's Status' RSS feed.